# Where are hash table implemented on the database or server code?

Tags: hashtable

I'm reading on hash table and data structure, and one question come to mind. Where is hash table implemented? Is it on server code or database?

The resource I've read seems to implement them on the server code, but isnt storing data the job of database? PS: I've havent get to a point of knowing non-sql database yet, maybe that's where my knowledge lack.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: I'm using c# and sql-server.But i think language doesnt apply to this question.

Comment: One of application of `hashTable` is `Database Indexing`. https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Many applications need to store some data internally, even if they're also using or updating data in a database at times.  Often they'll even retrieve related data from a remote (across the network) database and have it available in RAM on the local machine for the application to access quickly.

Other times, an application may use a data structure such as a hash table to support some application behaviours that are not part of the business data model, and therefore don't belong in the database.  For example, a GUI application might keep help strings to display when the mouse hovers over a widget/button/whatever - they might be stored in a hash table keyed on some GUI object identifier, screen region or whatever the GUI library finds useful to help it display the tooltips at the right time.  Another application might keep a table of usernames and activity statistics that it generated by scraping some website - it might display them to the user on demand, or aggregate them or something, without ever saving them down to a database (historic data may be of no value, and it can scrape the website again).

In summary - non-trivial programs tend to use hash tables to provide quick access to the data they consult or manipulate, whether the programs are themselves databases, applications that do also use databases, or applications that run without any database support.